# Proper way to create a class with a large amount of variables

Tags: python, validation, model, abstract-class

I have recently began to code after not doing so for years and I'm building a small project to get started again. It's a small application using a variety of crypto exchange markets dedicated APIs.

My question isn't about solving a problem it's about the proper way to solve it. Since, I dislike coding models that have a lot of variables, I decided to create an abstract model that will do the labor intensive part of defining variables for me.

Here's the question. When creating a class that requires many variables, should I:

1. Define every variable in the `__init__()` method as well as include every variable in the `__init__()` header

   *or*
2. Can I use my abstract class that only requires the defining of a list of variables that are needed and can I do this for my future projects?

My abstract class uses a 'static' list (python, I know) of variable names and implements the `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` way of building a dynamic / abstract object.

I don't know if an explicit bulky method or an implicit abstract method should be implemented for projects. What is the standard approach people/teams use in the real world?

**Examples**

Explicit Bulky Method

```
class Coin(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None, base_currency=None, quote_currency=None, base_min_size=None, base_max_size=None,
             quote_increment=None, base_increment=None, display_name=None, min_market_funds=None, max_market_funds=None,
             margin_enabled=None, post_only=None, limit_only=None, cancel_only=None, trading_disabled=None,
             status=None, status_message=None):
    self.id = id
    self.base_currency = base_currency
    self.quote_currency = quote_currency
    self.base_min_size = base_min_size
    self.base_max_size = base_max_size
    self.quote_increment = quote_increment
    self.base_increment = base_increment
    self.display_name = display_name
    self.min_market_funds = min_market_funds
    self.max_market_funds = max_market_funds
    self.margin_enabled = margin_enabled
    self.post_only = post_only
    self.limit_only = limit_only
    self.cancel_only = cancel_only
    self.trading_disabled = trading_disabled
    self.status = status
    self.status_message = status_message
```

Implicit abstract method

```
class EasyModel(object):
    """ Abstract Model. Use to create models that might have extensive variable members, or in cases where applicable. """

    __attrs__ = []

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_using_args(args) # set variables given as a *args
        self.set_using_kwargs(kwargs) # set variables given as **kwargs
        self.fill_empty() # Set variables that were expected to None

    def set_using_args(self, args):
        """ Given a list of variables (assuming in the correct order), add the value to the proper variable name. """
        for i, arg_value in enumerate(args):
            arg_name = self.__class__.__attrs__[i]
            setattr(self, arg_name, arg_value)

    def set_using_kwargs(self, kwargs):
        """ Given a dictionary, add the parameters as variables to the instance if the parameter is valid. """
        for arg_name, arg_value in kwargs.items():
            if (arg_name in self.__class__.__attrs__):
                setattr(self, arg_name, arg_value)

    def fill_empty(self):
        """ Create any undefined variables and set as None """
        for arg_name in self.__class__.__attrs__:
            if (not hasattr(self, arg_name)):
                setattr(self, arg_name, None)

    def __setattr__ (self, name, value):
        """ Make sure that the attributes that will be added are expected. """
        if (name in self.__class__.__attrs__):
            self.__dict__[name] = value


class Coin(EasyModel):
    """ Using the EasyModel to quickly build a model that will be created from an API request that gives all the data below in the form of a dictionary. """

    __attrs__ = ['id', 'base_currency', 'quote_currency', 'base_min_size', 'base_max_size',
                 'quote_increment', 'base_increment', 'display_name', 'min_market_funds', 'max_market_funds',
                 'margin_enabled', 'post_only', 'limit_only', 'cancel_only', 'trading_disabled', 'status', 'status_message']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Coin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

# Both would result in the same usage.
coin_data = {...} # Json / dictionary version of object

# Create object by passin json / dictionary as **kwargs
c = Coin(**coin_data)

# Both methods would result in this usage.
print (c.display_name)
```

Comment: I would suggest using a metaclass and make it do the labor-intensive definition of the class' attributes.

Comment: I forgot about meta-classes and how they work but thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Are meta-classes commonly used nowadays or do people just hard code the variables?

Comment: or look at dataclasses

Comment: I'll look at both. I know nothing about either so, it should be a good time to study them

Comment: Yes, I think metaclasses are fairly common, although [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses) as @Anthony suggested can take their place in many instances. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-TwcmT6Rcw) a very good talk on them by Raymond Hettinger.

Comment: When I implement both a dataclass and metaclass version should I post them here or should I close this question?

Comment: You can if you want and think it would help others — you're allowed to answer your own questions here (multiple times).

Comment: Cool I'll do that then. Thanks for the help. It's interesting so far. Starting off with https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/#:~:text=Python%20supports%20a%20form%20of%20metaprogramming%20for%20classes,you%20don%E2%80%99t%20need%20to%20be%20aware%20of%20it.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being harder than I thought. I barely scratched the surface of metaclasses and dataclasses but here is the solutions that I came up with including a working demo at the end.

I'm not sure which solution I am going to stick with.

```
# Required for dataclass
from dataclasses import dataclass

# Required to get coin data used in example.
import cbpro
    
""" Resources Used: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__new__-in-python/
https://www.pythonpool.com/python__new__/

I dont speak or read japanese but i found the snippets to be helpful.
https://python.ms/new/#_3-super-%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E7%94%9F%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82
"""    

############################################################################################################    
       
class CoinFunctions(object):
   """ A class of functionalities for a coin. All the class varients will inheirt this class. """

   def get_base_currency(self):
       return self.base_currency
   
############################################################################################################        
   
def create_coin(data):
   """ Dynamically Create a type/class and apply the CoinFunctions's methods. """
   
   coin_class = type("GeneratedCoin", (CoinFunctions,), data) # Build a new class. Still needs to be initialized
   c = coin_class()
   c.__dict__ = data
   return c  # Return an object initialized from the generated class.

############################################################################################################

class MetaCoin(CoinFunctions):
   """ class that implements the __new__ method. Haven't got into inheriting from metaclasses yet. """
   
  # Constructs the object to be initialized
   def __new__(cls, **kwargs):
       self = object.__new__(cls)
       self.__dict__ = kwargs
       return self # Returns the object 

   # Initializes the object.
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       pass
   
############################################################################################################       

@dataclass()
class Coin(CoinFunctions):
   """ A dataclass that is used to build a proper data set of a coin with built-in types. Inherit from CoinFunctions for functionalities"""
   
   id : str # base_currency-quote_currency (LTC-BTC)
   base_currency : str # (LTC)
   quote_currency : str # (BTC)
   base_min_size : str # float
   base_max_size : str # int / float
   quote_increment : str # double
   base_increment : str # double
   display_name : str
   min_market_funds : str # float
   max_market_funds : str # int / float
   margin_enabled : bool
   post_only : bool
   limit_only : bool
   cancel_only : bool
   trading_disabled : bool
   status : str
   status_message : str
    
############################################################################################################


""" 
This is my original solution. 

The __attrs__ field accepts a list of names that will be variables of the class.
The list of names that is __attrs__ are not only made into variables but are the only allowed variables.
If you want a variable in your class you must include its name inside of __attrs__.

When inheriting from EasyModel the only required ovveride is the __attrs__ field.
"""

class EasyModel(object):
   """ Abstract Model. Use to create models that might have extensive variable members, or in cases where applicable. """
   
   __attrs__ = []
   
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.set_using_args(args) # set variables given as a *args
       self.set_using_kwargs(kwargs) # set variables given as **kwargs
       self.fill_empty() # Set variables that were expected to None

   def set_using_args(self, args):
       """ Given a list of variables (assuming in the correct order), add the value to the proper variable name. """
       #print (self.__class__.__attrs__)
       for i, arg_value in enumerate(args):
           #print ("\n\n********* WORKING IN ARGS *********\n\n")
           arg_name = self.__class__.__attrs__[i]
           setattr(self, arg_name, arg_value)
               
   def set_using_kwargs(self, kwargs):
       """ Given a dictionary, add the parameters as variables to the instance if the parameter is valid. """
       for arg_name, arg_value in kwargs.items():
           #print (arg_name in self.__class__.__attrs__)
           if (arg_name in self.__class__.__attrs__):
               setattr(self, arg_name, arg_value)
       
   def fill_empty(self):
       """ Create any undefined variables and set as None """
       for arg_name in self.__class__.__attrs__:
           if (not hasattr(self, arg_name)):
               setattr(self, arg_name, None)
           
   def __setattr__ (self, name, value):
       """ Make sure that the attributes that will be added are expected. """
       if (name in self.__class__.__attrs__):
           self.__dict__[name] = value
           




class EasyCoin(EasyModel):
   """ Using the EasyModel to quickly build a model that will be created from an API request that gives all the data below in the form of a dictionary. """ 

   __attrs__ = ['id', 'base_currency', 'quote_currency', 'base_min_size', 'base_max_size', 
                'quote_increment', 'base_increment', 'display_name', 'min_market_funds', 'max_market_funds', 
                'margin_enabled', 'post_only', 'limit_only', 'cancel_only', 'trading_disabled', 'status', 'status_message']
 
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(EasyCoin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       
       




       
#########################################################################################################################################
#########################################################################################################################################

# Executing The Code: 
if __name__ == '__main__':
   
   # Make a connection to coinbase pro and request a list of their crypto trade markets.
   client = cbpro.PublicClient()
   
   #list_of_coins = client.get_currencies() # an actual list of coins
   list_of_coins = client.get_products() # a list of supported crypto trades. 
   
   
    
   # Each item in the list_of_coins is a dictionary. 
   for coin_data in list_of_coins:
       
       c = create_coin(coin_data)
       
       print ("")
       print ("Type:", type(c))
       print ("Class Bases:", c.__class__.__bases__)
       print ("Object:",c)
       print ("Object.__dict__", c.__dict__)
       
       c = MetaCoin(**coin_data)
       
       print ("")
       print ("Type:", type(c))
       print ("Class Bases:", c.__class__.__bases__)
       print ("Object:",c)
       print ("Object.__dict__", c.__dict__)        
              
       c = Coin(**coin_data)
       
       print ("")
       print ("Type:", type(c))
       print ("Class Bases:", c.__class__.__bases__)
       print ("Object:",c)
       print ("Object.__dict__", c.__dict__)
       
       c = EasyCoin(**coin_data) 

       print ("")
       print ("Type:", type(c))
       print ("Class Bases:", c.__class__.__bases__)
       print ("Object:",c)
       print ("Object.__dict__", c.__dict__)
       
       break
```

#### Output

```
Type: <class '__main__.GeneratedCoin'>
Class Bases: (<class '__main__.CoinFunctions'>,)
Object: <__main__.GeneratedCoin object at 0x043867D0>
Object.__dict__ {'id': 'LINK-USD', 'base_currency': 'LINK', 'quote_currency': 'USD', 'base_min_size': '0.1', 'base_max_size': '90000', 'quote_increment': '0.00001', 'base_increment': '0.01', 'display_name': 'LINK/USD', 'min_market_funds': '10', 'max_market_funds': '100000', 'margin_enabled': False, 'post_only': False, 'limit_only': False, 'cancel_only': False, 'trading_disabled': False, 'status': 'online', 'status_message': ''}

Type: <class '__main__.MetaCoin'>
Class Bases: (<class '__main__.CoinFunctions'>,)
Object: <__main__.MetaCoin object at 0x04386730>
Object.__dict__ {'id': 'LINK-USD', 'base_currency': 'LINK', 'quote_currency': 'USD', 'base_min_size': '0.1', 'base_max_size': '90000', 'quote_increment': '0.00001', 'base_increment': '0.01', 'display_name': 'LINK/USD', 'min_market_funds': '10', 'max_market_funds': '100000', 'margin_enabled': False, 'post_only': False, 'limit_only': False, 'cancel_only': False, 'trading_disabled': False, 'status': 'online', 'status_message': ''}

Type: <class '__main__.Coin'>
Class Bases: (<class '__main__.CoinFunctions'>,)
Object: Coin(id='LINK-USD', base_currency='LINK', quote_currency='USD', base_min_size='0.1', base_max_size='90000', quote_increment='0.00001', base_increment='0.01', display_name='LINK/USD', min_market_funds='10', max_market_funds='100000', margin_enabled=False, post_only=False, limit_only=False, cancel_only=False, trading_disabled=False, status='online', status_message='')
Object.__dict__ {'id': 'LINK-USD', 'base_currency': 'LINK', 'quote_currency': 'USD', 'base_min_size': '0.1', 'base_max_size': '90000', 'quote_increment': '0.00001', 'base_increment': '0.01', 'display_name': 'LINK/USD', 'min_market_funds': '10', 'max_market_funds': '100000', 'margin_enabled': False, 'post_only': False, 'limit_only': False, 'cancel_only': False, 'trading_disabled': False, 'status': 'online', 'status_message': ''}

Type: <class '__main__.EasyCoin'>
Class Bases: (<class '__main__.EasyModel'>,)
Object: <__main__.EasyCoin object at 0x043867D0>
Object.__dict__ {'id': 'LINK-USD', 'base_currency': 'LINK', 'quote_currency': 'USD', 'base_min_size': '0.1', 'base_max_size': '90000', 'quote_increment': '0.00001', 'base_increment': '0.01', 'display_name': 'LINK/USD', 'min_market_funds': '10', 'max_market_funds': '100000', 'margin_enabled': False, 'post_only': False, 'limit_only': False, 'cancel_only': False, 'trading_disabled': False, 'status': 'online', 'status_message': ''}
```